# Why are my arrays returning no values?

Tags: php, sql

I have this php script set up to gather column data from my sql table and put each column's data into an array. When I echo my array it displays zero values for my array. The result is just 'Array'. I am omitting my DB connection info from the submission code, but it is successfully connected to the DB.

```
 //Connecting to the DB
$link = mysql_connect(DB_Host, DB_User, DB_Password);

if (!$link) {
    die('Could Not Connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_Name, $link);

if (!db_selected) {
    die('Can\'t use ' . DB_Name . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

//Putting job submission address column into an array
$result_while = mysql_query("SELECT address 
  FROM jobsubmission");

$client_array = array();
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_while)) {
$client_array[] = $row2['address'];
}

echo $client_array;

//Putting driver submission address column into an array
$result_while2 = mysql_query("SELECT address 
    FROM DriverInformation");

$driver_array = array();
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_while2)) {
$driver_array[] = $row3['address'];
}

//replaces space with "+" sign for concetenation
$address1 = str_replace(' ', '+', $submission_array);
$address2 = str_replace(' ', '+', $driver_array);

//Google Distance Matrix API string--Sends all informtion through the
 API and performs calculation
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?
origins=$address1&destinations=$address2&mode=driving&language=English-      
en&key=APIKEY";

//Return of API data--formatted to just display the distance of quickest 
route
$json = file_get_contents($url); // get the data from Google Maps API
$result = json_decode($json, true); // convert it from JSON to php array
$results_submission = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['distance']['text'];


?>
```

Comment: dont use `echo`, use `print_r( $client_array);`

Comment: Enable error reporting, when you want to debug code. Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/845021/3933332

Comment: since your just starting - stop with mysql its going to be removed

Comment: @Rizier123 no error its just `echo $client_array;`

Comment: @Dagon When? This is what my webhost provided

Comment: "Warning

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information."

Comment: @Dagon Notice: Array to String ;)

Comment: @Dagon yeah haha. How do I change the spaces in an array to "+" ? It's necessary for the google matrix API

Comment: @Jb11281992 sounds like you should be using `urlencode`

Comment: @Rizier123 pft Notices dont count ;)